# lixml2 C xpath fails with "invalid expression"

Tags: c, xpath, libxml2

I use libxml2 in C application to parse XML files.

I get an error when I search for XPath with special character '$'.

Here my code :

```
xmlXPathExpression("//mytag/foo$");
```

And I get error "Invalid expression".

I tried to encode speical characters like this :

```
xmlXPathExpression("//mytag/foo&#36;");
```

But I get same error.

Any help ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see `$` listed as a valid character in element name: [XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar).

Comment: So i can't use any special character in xml element name ?

Comment: You can use thousands of different characters in an XML element name, but not currency symbols.